# How to Map JSON Property by Index rather than Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, typescript

I have webapplication i have following JSON Array:

```
var data=[ 
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },
 { "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },
 { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } 
];
```

i want to get `hits` field in a one saparate table like
var hits = [5,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,1]

I know about `data.map(x=>x.hits)`
but my properties name in json are dynamic. i dont know my property name in advance. so i need to use index of properties in Json.

i know it is possible using loop through the json,

but is there any way to get all `hits` in one statement without any loop ?

Comment: Use `Object.keys()` to get an array of all available properties of a JSON object. Then you may loop through them regardless of their values

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON array" or "JSON object". [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (it can be an array, an object or a primitive type as a number or a string as well). The text you posted is JavaScript code, not JSON.

Comment: You said *i dont know my property name* but you want  *get all hits* what you mean?

Comment: It seems like depending on keys being in a certain order is very fragile.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
let prop = 'hits';

data.map(x => x[prop]);
```

Reassign `prop` to be the desired property name.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get a key using Object.keys. then just put a Map function to achieve your task.

```
var data=[ 
     { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },
     { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
     { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },
     { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },
     { "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },
     { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },
     { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
     { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },
     { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } 
    ];
var KeyName=Object.keys(data[0])[1]
data.map(x => x[KeyName]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet is:

```
var data=[ 
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },
 { "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },
 { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } 
];

var idx = 1; // key2

var key = Object.keys(data)[idx];
value = o[key]

console.log(key,value); // key2 value2
```

You can use this also:

```
    var data=[ 
     { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },
     { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
     { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },
     { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },
     { "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },
     { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },
     { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
     { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },
     { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } 
    ];

for(var prop in data) {
  console.log(prop,data[prop]);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two different approachs. If the key are dynamic but you know through a variable what key you are looking for you can go for :

```
const keyname = 'hits';
data.map(x => x[keyname])
```

where keyname is a variable you set according to your needs.

If it can work only thanks to an index for some reasons, you have to get the keyname from the index thanks to this formula :

```
const j = 0; // or increment j through a for loop
const index = 3; // the index of the key you need
let keyname = Object.keys(data[j])[index];
data.map(x => x[keyname]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use the of the position of the key arrays generated by `Objcet.keys()`:

```js
var data = [ 
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },
 { "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },
 { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } 
];

var res = data.map(item => {
  var k = Object.keys(item);
  return item[k[1]];
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't know if the objects in your `data` array will have a property `hits` or not. Or maybe it will be spelled differently.

This is one way to work with such case

```js
var data=[ 
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "HITS" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hit" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "HIT" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },
 { "category" : "Business", "bytes" : 2847 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },
 { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } 
];


data.forEach(function(obj){
  //first, get an array of all availble keys in current element
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  
  //now we loop through all obtained keys
  keys.forEach(function(key){
  
    // the following line will match HIT/HITS/hit/hits
    if(key.toUpperCase().indexOf("HIT")>-1) {
       console.log("found hits: " , obj[key]);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you meant correctly, your data is an array, and this array contains some values. But maybe one of them doesn't have the property `hits`. So, you don't want to use `map` method because the result may contain `undefined` value(s)?

If it is your problem, you can try to use `filter` method after mapping. Like this:

```js
    var arr = [
        {
            'hits': 1
        },
        {
            'hits': 2
        },
        {
            'foo': 'bar'
        },
        {
            'hits': 3
        },
        {
            'hits': 4
        }
    ];

    var hits = arr.map(x => x.hits).filter(x => x);

    console.log(hits);
```

After mapping, the result should be:

> [1, 2, undefined, 3, 4]

Then, we need to filter it to:

> [1, 2, 3, 4]